# How to create a class instance from slick query?

Tags: scala, slick

I am finding it difficult to figure out the best wy to create an instance of a class (a DTO class) which can be passed as json to the calling client.

I have the following class structure.

```
object Suppliers extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)]("SUPPLIERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def city = column[String]("CITY")
  def state = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip = column[String]("ZIP")
  def * = id ~ name ~ street ~ city ~ state ~ zip
}

object Coffees extends Table[(Int,String, Double,Int, Int)]("COFFEES") {
  def id = column[Int]("Id",O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total = column[Int]("TOTAL")
  def * = id ~ name ~ price ~ sales ~ total
}

object CoffeeSuppliers extends Table[(Int,Int,Int)]("CoffeeSuppliers") {
    def id = column[Int]("Id",O.PrimaryKey)
    def supID = column[Int]("Sup_ID")
    def coffeeID = column[Int]("Coffee_ID")
    def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, Suppliers)(_.id) 
    def coffees = foreignKey("COF_FK", coffeeID,Coffees)(_.id)
    def * = id ~ supID ~ coffeeID
}
```

I am using this simple join query to retrieve Supplier with id 101 and all the coffees he supplies.

```
            val q3 = for {
          ((cs,c),s) <- CoffeeSuppliers innerJoin 
                        Coffees on (_.coffeeID === _.id) innerJoin 
                        Suppliers on (_._1.supID === _.id) if cs.supID === 101 
        } yield (cs,c,s)
```

The query is working fine and I am able to retrieve the data. 
But, I want to construct a DTO class out of the query result. The Class structure is as fallows

```
  case class CoffeeDTO(
                       id:Option[Int] = Some(0),
                       name:String[String] = "",
                       price:Double= 0.0
                      )
  case class SupplierDTO (
                      id:Option[Int] = Some(0),
                      name:String = "",
                      coffees:List[CoffeeDTO] = Nil
  )
```

How to create an instance of SupplierDTO and assign the values from the query result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
q3.map{ case (cs,c,s) => ((s.id.?,s.name),(c.id.?,c.name,c.price)) } // remove not needed columns and make ids Options
  .list // run query
  .groupBy( _._1 ) // group by supplier
  .map{ case (s,scPairs) => SupplierDTO( s._1, // map each group to a supplier with associated coffees
                                     s._2,
                                     scPairs.map(_._2) // map group of pairs to only coffee tuples
                                            .map(CoffeeDTP.tupled) // create coffee objects
  )}
  .head // take just the one supplier out of the list
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.The comments helped me to understand what was going on. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What this does is it will run a SQL query to return the data, and once you have your list of data you need to loop over that entire dataset again to transform it to the DTO you want.  This seems like a pretty big performance hit.  Is there no way of running the query that returns the result set directly into the DTO?

Comment: Not at the moment, but you don't need to do it, you can also iterate over the data as it comes from Slick in the place where you actually need it.